# OpenTBS - Manipulation de ligne de tableaux

Tags: php, opentbs

I have been working with TBS and I wanted to know if it is possible to interact with the tables present in a pptx in order to make it dynamic?

The pptx was created from a MAC and when I insert text areas myself, they are only taken into account by the onshow and not VarRef is this normal?

I am using a translator, sorry for the understanding :)

Have a nice day !

Answer (score 0):

Yes is it possible to interact with tables in a PPTX the same way as for a DOCX.

The difference is that when a table of a PPTX is too long, the overflow cannot be seen in the next slide. Overflow in a slide is always hidden. This is a PPTX thing.